# jQuery UI Dialog issues with IE7 and IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I have an Asp.Net webforms page that contains a hidden .Net user control (hidden.ascx) that is displayed in a jQuery UI Dialog when a button is clicked.  Now, this works fine in IE9 and Chrome.

However, in IE8 the dialog is pushed to the bottom of the page rather than being centered.

In IE7, the dialog is centered but read-only (in that all controls within the dialog are read-only...I also cannot close the dialog by clicking the 'x' in the top right corner - essentially the entire page is unusable until I refresh the page).

I am using **jQuery 1.5.1** and **jQuery UI 1.8.11** and made sure to add references for core, dialog, position, and widget.

Here is the jQuery call that displays the hidden user control:

```
 $('#button').click(function(){
  showUserControl();
});

function showUserControl(){
  var d = $('#container').dialog({
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'show .net user control',
    width: 500,
    show: 'puff',    
  }).height('auto');

  d.dialog("open");
}
```

Here is some of the hidden.ascx control (simplified for this post):

```
<fieldset id="container" class="layoverForm" style="display: none">   

    <div id="status">
        <asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsErrors" ValidationGroup="audit" ShowSummary="true" DisplayMode="BulletList" runat="server" />
    </div>    
    <div class="row">
        <span class="label">Choose One:<b>*</b></span>
        <span class="control">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="cboPickList" ValidationGroup="audit" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvPickList" ValidationGroup="form" ControlToValidate="cboPickList" InitialValue="" Display="None" Text="*" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please choose one."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" />
    </div> </fieldset>
```

As you can see, pretty simple stuff really.  However, I can't seem to find a way around this issue so any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: A quick update on this issue...in order to be able to submit the form from w/in the dialog, I added the open event when defining my dialog & defined the zIndex:
    var d = $('#container').dialog({
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'show .net user control',
    width: 500,
     **open: function(event, ui){
      $(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:last");
     },
     zIndex: 3999**,
     show: 'puff',    
    }).height('auto');
 
This has fixed my issue with IE8, but because I have modal set to true the issue with IE7 is till giving me a rash.

Comment: If I set modal to false, IE7 is okay with that but obviously makes the parent page editable which is bad.  I guess I could just do a $.ajax post rather than leveraging the <form> on the parent page, but the functionality right now is working well in all other browsers except for IE7.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in IE7 in order to make the modal work correctly you must also attach the div that catches clicks to the same place you append the dialog div. Adding `$('.ui-widget-overlay').appendTo('form:first');` to the openOn function of the popup should fix the problem. So the whole declaration block would look like this:

```
function showUserControl(){
    var d = $('#container').dialog({
    modal: true,
    position: 'center',
    autoOpen: false,
    title: 'show .net user control',
    width: 500,
    show: 'puff',
    open: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:last"));
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').appendTo('form:first');
    },
  }).height('auto');

  d.dialog("open");
}
```